# layer.zPosition does not work with non-sibling UIViews

Tags: iphone, graphics, uiimageview, quartz-graphics, layer

I have a reasonably complex hierarchy of `UIImageView`s.  Originally, I was carefully swapping the sibling order when one `UIImageView` moved in front of another.  Then I found out about `myUIImageView.layer.zPosition` and switched to using this instead.  Worked out much simpler.  It even works *almost* all the time.  I found out from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537042/how-to-change-a-uiview-zposition) that `zPosition` only works amongst sibling layers.  Great!  So I have two questions really: Is there any actual documentation about this? and, is there some kind of fudge I can use to get this to work? (like adding all my UIImageViews to a UIView that is never visible).  Thx in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the title of your question, I wonder if you understand that the `zPosition` property works with sibling **layers**, not sibling views. To deal with the depth of every image you have with the `zPosition` property, you will need to have all the images as sibling layers within one single UIView object. The `zPosition` property is documented in Apple's [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/LayerTreeHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006083-SW1):

> The zPosition property specifies the z-axis component of the layer's position. The zPosition is intended to be used to set the visual position of the layer relative to its sibling layers. It should not be used to specify the order of layer siblings, instead reorder the layer in the sublayer array.

Comment: @MHC OK, thanks, so if I make all my layers siblings, perhaps by adding them  as sublayers to my "root" UIView layer, will that mess with my UIView hierarchy?

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011 - What do you mean by "didn't work"?  If you add all UIViews as subviews of one main view (so that they are all siblings), you should be able to control their relative stacking using the `zPosition` property on their layers.

Comment: @MHC, @Brad.  When I said "didn't work" I was talking about what I suggested in my earlier comment--adding my layers as sublayers of my "root" UIView layer.  It seems, on iOS at least, the layer hierarchy and UIView hierarchy are effectively the same thing--you can't mess with one without effecting the other.  I was hoping I could get `zPosition` to work by making all my layers siblings, without effecting my UIView hierarchy.  I have thought about this and I think I can do enough of what I want by using zPosition on the "main" GUI elements--all siblings on the 1st level of my UIView hierarchy.

Comment: Making all layers siblings already implies the UIView hierarchy need to change. For example, if you put all your visual elements as layers of a UIView object, only one UIView object would remain and no view hierarchy there. So I can't see how you made all of the visual elements sibling layers without changing the view hierarchy. I guess we must have some communication errors here. Anyway, the layer hierarchy and UIView hierarchy are NOT the same thing - even if they might behave 'effectively' the same for some cases in some iOS versions, you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011 - UIViews cannot simultaneously be siblings of one another and children / parents, so you either have an ordered hierarchy or a flattened grouping of views.  You also can't have a different hierarchy for your UIViews than their hosted layers (although you can create independent layers that exist away from the UIViews).  Think of each layer / view as a flat plane.  `zPosition` only controls the ordering within that plane.  If something is a subview or sublayer, it exists in a different plane above the parent.  Only by flattening everything does `zPosition` matter.

Comment: @MHC,@Brad.  Thx for your comments.  I think I have it.  I was using `addSublayer` to try and create a "flat" layer hierarchy, independent to my `UIView` hierarchy.  Didn't work.  I must choose between the inconvenience of creating my own "manual" hierarchy (with a global `zPosition`), or swapping subViews between `UIViews`, or just having limited control over the ordering of my graphical elements (or perhaps switching to cocos2d).