# How to make sure UIView is on top of SKScene?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit

Is there any Objective-C code for making sure a UIView is always on top of an SKScene when called upon? I'm calling this UIView from an SKScene during game play inside my SpriteKit game by clicking a button. The tint activates but this UIView (Options screen) image is not on top of all the SKScene images.

Comment: Change the z component of the UIView to make it go in front of all others.

Comment: UIView zPosition does not always achieve the desired result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466116/layer-zposition-does-not-work-with-non-sibling-uiviews

Comment: See Linus G's answer.

Comment: But make sure you look at the link that sangony posted, it should help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `.zPosition` to arrange UI elements' order on the zAxis.

Therefore you can use any numbers.
You can use `.zPosition = 1` or with `.zPosition = 9876.26`. The only important thing is to make the numbers different. If the number is smaller, the element is lower / behind the other ones. If the number is larger, it is on top.

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: Ok. In SKScene I use _object.zPosition = 10.0; for instance. But those are images inside SKScene. How do I make a separate UIView zPosition on top of an SKScene.zPosition?

Comment: then access the objects themselves?