# Dynamically hide or position video above dots in UIPageViewcontroller (e.g., UIPageControl)?

Tags: uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Is it possible to position a video above a `UIPageControl` (i.e., the dots of a `UIPageViewController`)?

One of the view controllers managed by a `UIPageViewController` shows a video when the user taps on it.

After the tap, is it possible to position the video above the dots? Setting the `zPosition` of the video view higher than the `UIPageControl` failed, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466939/144088) explains `zPosition` has no effect unless the `UIPageControl` and the video are siblings.

From other StackOverflow answers, it doesn't seem possible to dynamically hide the dots, which would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 4 answer to dynamically hide dots:

**Works:**

```
for subview in self.view.subviews {
    if subview is UIPageControl {
        subview.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

**Fails:**

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [type(of: self)])
pageControl.isHidden = true
```