# can CALayer in IOS transform in z position

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, calayer

I have CAlayers in different z-depth and i want to transform them in z depth to see all layers i tried using this method:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0,-50 );
rootLayer.sublayerTransform = transform;
```

but no change 
and i tried using this method

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DRotate(trackball->baseTransform, 30, 30 , 0 , 0 );
rootLayer.sublayerTransform = transform;
for (CALayer* layer in rootLayer.sublayers)
{
    CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"zPosition"];
    theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-40]; // [NSNumber numberWithFloat:frandom(800, 400)];
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:200]; // [NSNumber numberWithFloat:frandom(-300, -100)];
    theAnimation.duration=8;
    theAnimation.repeatCount = 1e100;
    [layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"zPosition"];
}
```

It moved in y direction

Note :Ipad orientation is landscape.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stack images to simulate depth using Core Animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834985/how-do-i-stack-images-to-simulate-depth-using-core-animation)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the code you supplied doesn't discover the problem

Suppose we have the following structure

```
-> rootLayer
    -> sublayer1
    -> sublayer2
    -> sublayer3
    ...
    -> sublayerN
```

Then to get visible the `sublayer2` you will need to change `zPosition` to the `sublayer1` but not to the `rootLayer`