# How to draw inside a layer and add to context only after [viewLayer addSublayer:newLayer]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, calayer, cgcontext

### The question

How do you create a separate context for your layer and incorporate that context into super layer?

### Why I want to do this

I want abstract the drawing of a view layers into separate objects/files. I want to construct a view out of layers, then position then on top of one another and have other possibilities as that.

The problem is that I'm not aware of you you're supposed to draw a part of your view into a layer **without** drawing straight into the context of the main views sublayer.

Here's an example, I have subclassed `CALayer` with `HFFoundation`:

```
@implementation HFFoundation

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    UIBezierPath *foundation = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    // some drawing goes on here in the form of messages to [foundation]
}

@end
```

Now when I instantiate my custom layer inside a views `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` I this way:

```
HFFoundation *foundation = [HFFoundation new];
foundation.frame = CGRectMake(40, viewHeight - 100, 300, 100);
foundation.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:.4 blue:1 alpha:0.2] CGColor];

[self.window.rootViewController.view.layer addSublayer:foundation];
```

I get this result (no drawings appear, just the bg color inside the layer frame):

[image: adding a sublayer]

If I `[foundation drawLayer:foundation inContext:context];` afterwards, the drawing appears, but it appears inside the top layers context, not in `foundation` layer. Since `foundation` layer is also lower in the hierarchy, it hides the drawing (unless I reduce it's alpha, which I've dont in the picture):

[image: it draws straight into the context]

How do you draw into the layer itself, I.e. `foundation` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a sublayer and set its index you want this piece of code:

```
[view.layer insertSublayer:foundation atIndex:0];
```

Comment: @jonahthan, this only changes the fact that my drawing inside of the layer, surfaces up over the frame, but subsequently if I try to change the `zPosition` of a layer, the only thing that moves is it's `frame`. How do I adjust the depth of the drawing of a layer?

Comment: I don't think I really understand what you mean. but maybe this is what you want to read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834985/how-do-i-stack-images-to-simulate-depth-using-core-animation also check out this answer