# How to drag a row between other rows in UITableView or UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement the view shown in the animation below:

[image]

I found a great control called `TGLStackedViewController` which does almost what I need. The way it performs the moving is by taking a snapshot of the card you want to move and adding it as a subview to the collectionView, while hiding the original card. When dragging has stopped the movable view is removed and the original card is made visible again.

This works well, but doesn't produce the result I want since the movable view covers all cards. I wish for the card being moved to always be *between* the two cells above and below, just like in the animation. But I am not sure how to do this since all items are on the same level. I would really like to avoid making a completely custom view control and if possible do this with either `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`.

Comment: u want to do it in edit mode or normally?

Comment: Preferably in the normal state, but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I have done somethng like dragging a cell from one position to other, but in edit table mode .better u should use views for this, i guess

Comment: Yeah, I fear I might have to do this, but I still hope there is a more out-of-the-box approach :)

Comment: Yeah...3 tableview methods do this, canMoveRowAtIndexPath , moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath,  targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath. u can start looking into these.

Comment: I am aware of those methods :) In fact, I used them when working with `TGLStackedViewController`. My issue is not how to perform a move, but rather how to have the moving view placed inbetween other rows.

Comment: swift or objc? can you provide any code?

Comment: I have plenty of code, but all of the solutions I have tried so far lack some aspect of the desired behaviour. Currently I am making an manual implementation just using a scroll view and regular views. I think I will be able to make it work.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `zPosition` along with the index of the card to give the depth you are looking for (so they look like they're going in between). To see more in depth please check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834985/how-do-i-stack-images-to-simulate-depth-using-core-animation)